# jquery $.post not working unless debugging

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have simple form for updating the stock of products, it uses datatables to generate rows for all the items in the database. I can update the stock correctly using the form when I set a break point in the function, but if I remove the break point it stops working.

HTML form:

```
<form id="updateStock">
  <input id="Penguincard" type="text" value="200">
  <input type="submit" onclick="updateStock("Penguincard", "Penguin card");" value="Update">                            
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateStock(id, item){
    var idS = "#" + id;
    var newStock = $(idS).val();
    $.post("URL",{item: item, stock: newStock},  
        function(result){           
            alert(result);
        });
    return false;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Adds a new item to the database
require('common.php');



if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){  
    if (empty($_POST["item"])){
        echo 'item is blank';
        exit();
    }else
    {
        $item = test_input($_POST["item"]);
        // check if item only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$item))
        {
            echo 'item reg';
            exit();
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["stock"])) {
        echo 'stock is blank';
        exit();
    }else
    {
        $stock = test_input($_POST["stock"]);
        // check if stock only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$stock))
        {
            echo 'stock reg';
            exit();
        }
    }   

}else{
    //don't run unless post
    echo 'Not post';
    exit();
}

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE `stock` SET `stock`=:stock WHERE `item`=:item');

// bind the parameters to the insert after sanitizing them
$stmt->bindParam(':item', $item);
$stmt->bindParam(':stock', $stock);




//execute the insert
$status = $stmt->execute();

if( $status ){
    echo 'Item added successfully!';
    exit();     
}


//sanitizing function
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}


?>
```

EDIT: by not working I mean it seems to run the onClick function but doesn't submit the post.

From the answers it seems that debugging was allowing the post to be submitted before the default form action occurred, therefore making it working.

Comment: What do you mean by, "it stops working"?  *How* exactly does it fail? What happens that you don't expect? Are there errors reported?

Comment: You should not use the " character inside the HTML attributes, use ', or you might encounter escaping problems. However I don't know if that causes the issue.

Comment: @UliKöhler, that is probably why indeed. Because it is not calling the `updateStock` function.

Comment: @UliKöhler that is correct but then why debugging makes it work? Strange...

Comment: I have updated the question with my findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never actually suppressing the `click` functionality of the submit button; you `return false;` from the updateStock function, but that doesn't actually do anything (the `onclick` attributes code itself needs to be returning false. As a result the form is being submitted and the AJAX request is cancelled.

The simplest fix would be this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return updateStock('Penguincard', 'Penguin card');" value="Update">
```

However, it would probably be better to use jQuery to bind the event handler:

```
$(':submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateStock('Penguincard', 'Penguin card');
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Just copied straight from the question; I've changed them to single quotes now.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution is better for me, didn't realize it never returned.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the issue:

```
onclick="updateStock("Penguincard", "Penguin card");"
```

The double quotes inside the attribute are the problem. Convert them to single quotes. This is one reason why people like to use the jQuery delegates to add click events.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, it's invalid markup...http://jsfiddle.net/HZe5k/